# Incredibly high latency for Ubuntu guest on Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

I've got several Ubuntu 10.04 virtual machines running as Hyper-V guests on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and they're all perfectly fine.

Today I installed my first Ubuntu 11.10 virtual machine and I'm seeing rediculous pings:

[image]

These servers are all connected via gigabit to a local LAN, with almost no network traffic at all<sup>1</sup>, with a legacy network adapter in Hyper-V.

I'm a bit of an Ubuntu n00b so I don't really know where to go from here. Any ideas?

---

`free -m` reports:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           485        470         15          0         63        299
-/+ buffers/cache:        107        378
Swap:          507         20        487
```

This is within a few mb of our other Ubuntu servers that are on 10.04.

---

I removed the Legacy NIC and installed a Synthetic one in Hyper-V and this *did* improve the numbers, in that they're around 10-30ms now, but I would still be expecting <1ms response times.

<sub><sup>1</sup>As a comparison, I have another Ubuntu 10.04 guest on Hyper-V almost 1,000km away that has a ping of 33ms</sub>

Comment: Have you verified that pings to the physical machine are not being lost as well, to ensure networking issues aren't present, or tried pinging directly from the host machine to one of the virtual machines?

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler - yep, pings to the physical host are correct (`<1ms`)

Comment: What does `free -m` on the virtual system report?

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler - updated question

Comment: Updated the latest 11.10 kernel?  Any differences in integration components between your 10.04 builds and 11.10?

Comment: @Mark Well, it doesn't look like you're facing heavy swapping, which was my first guess.

Comment: @evilensky - Yeah, did an update just after the installation. As for components, it acted in that way right after a standard blank install with no components selected. They're being used as a really, really light-on proxy. One thing I did do was swap a legacy adapter for a synthetic one and that *did* improve things, but not as much as I would have liked.

Comment: And there's nothing going on with the host -- memory oversubscription,  or dynamic memory that's favoring the other child partitions over this one?

Comment: @evilensky - nope. It's a new server with a buttload of RAM and almost no VM's on it yet. Total of 12 cores with virtually no CPU load, and fixed memory (even if it is only 512Mb). Other VM's on there (windows ones) have <1ms latency.

Comment: wtf? Problem has gone away on its own now. Sorry for wasting everyones time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a new system, it may have needed to download and install quite a few updated packages.  If the slowness is still present, try doing something like

```
ps -ef|grep apt
```

on the virtual machine to see if there's an apt-related process running.  If the slowness suddenly resolved itself, it's worth checking `/var/log/dpkg.log` to see if a bunch of packages were installed, causing the slowness.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has gone away on its own. Sorry I don't have a better answer than that.

I realise this is like [pushing the green button](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/press-the-green-button-twice/) but as this is not a mission critical production machine, I'm going to count my blessings and move on.

For what it's worth, switching to a synthentic NIC rather than a legacy NIC made a huge difference, but did not alleviate the problem completely.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but check /var/log/dpkg.log on the new system. Maybe apt had to update a whole bunch of packages, and the downloading/installing was affecting response time.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler - and you win a gold star. There's hundreds of entries in that log that all end at about the time I went to lunch. Post that as an answer and I'll give it the checkmark.

Comment: Done.  Glad the mystery was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but still a reply; make sure after installing you remove the nic and then add a 'synthetic NIC' within Hyper-V. Ubuntu has the correct drivers for it and as far as I know it will use paravirtualization that way. Also on Windows guests OS'es you'll really want the synthetic NIC.

Answer (score 1):

Are `hv_netvsc`, `hv_blkvsc`, `hv_storvsc` and `hv_vmbus` kernel modules loaded on the guest? I run Ubuntu 10.04 under Hyper-V and ping is under 1ms. You can check modules using `sudo lsmod | grep hv` command.

Comment: Yep, all loaded. The problem has just gone away on its own in the last hour or so after doing absolutally nothing to it (I went out to lunch and came back).